# Display XML in a WPF textbox

Tags: wpf, xml, textbox

It is simple enough to put the outer text of an XML node in a WPF text box. But is there a way to get the text box to format the text as an XML document? Is there a different control that does that?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
    protected string FormatXml(string xmlString)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        doc.LoadXml(xmlString);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        System.IO.TextWriter tr = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb);

        XmlTextWriter wr = new XmlTextWriter(tr);

        wr.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

        doc.Save(wr);

        wr.Close();

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can attach to the binding a converter and call inside the converter to formatting code.

This is example code that formats XML:

```
public string FormatXml(string xml)
{
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    var xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
                                  {Indent = true, OmitXmlDeclaration = true};
    doc.Save(XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder, xmlWriterSettings));
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

And a test demonstrates the usage:

```
public void TestFormat()
{
    string xml = "<root><sub/></root>";
    string expectedXml = "<root>" + Environment.NewLine +
                         "  <sub />" + Environment.NewLine +
                         "</root>";
    string formattedXml = FormatXml(xml);

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedXml, formattedXml);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a different control that does that?

Yes, just display the xml in a browser control.

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="wbOriginalXml" />
```

Simply navigate to a saved xml

```
wbOriginalXml.Navigate( new Uri(@"C:\TempResult\Manifest.xml") );
```

The *results* are automatically *tree-ed* in the browser where the nodes can be collapsed:

[image]

Comment: This only works on XML files, not on in-memory XML variables

Comment: @DdW Yes one would have to save to a temporary file if the XML is in memory.

Comment: A little late to the party, but you can do WebBrowser.NavigateToString to display an in-memory XML. No need to save to a temp file. I found this the absolute easiest and nicest way to visualize XML in WPF

Comment: @hcd Sounds good. Let the others know, so If you want you can update my answer with an example or provide an answer.