# How to show parsed xml in TextBlock in WPF?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml

I have `TextBlock` with name **XML_View**, also I know `.xml` file location `string filename = dlg.FileName;`

So I want to show xml n that `TextBlock`,  I found a possible solution here ([Display XML in a WPF textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702893/display-xml-in-a-wpf-textbox)), it gives as a function, like this:

```
protected string FormatXml(string xmlString)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    System.IO.TextWriter tr = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb);
    XmlTextWriter wr = new XmlTextWriter(tr);
    wr.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    doc.Save(wr);
    wr.Close();
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

If I get required string, I might just simply write  `XML_View.Text = String_xml;` or something like this. But I don't know how to get string if I have `.xml` file and I don't know how to use such a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've modified your function to take as parameter the filename to read your xml from. Make sure the file exists in your bin directory (or you use an absolute path like @"C:\temp\myfile.xml" to resolve).

```
protected string FormatXml(string xmlFile)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(xmlFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    doc.Load(fs);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    System.IO.TextWriter tr = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb);
    XmlTextWriter wr = new XmlTextWriter(tr);
    wr.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    doc.Save(wr);
    wr.Close();
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace

```
doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
```

with

```
doc.Load(xmlFilePath);
```

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642293/how-do-i-read-and-parse-an-xml-file-in-c) as reference.